# Unit testing for Exception in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to pass my unit test in flutter. i'm getting my expected value and actual value still my test got failed.

**This is my Method in BaseApi class.**

*Exception getNetErrorException(String url) => HttpException(url);*

**and this is my test :**

```
group("getNetErrorException", () {
  test("Should throw a HttpException when there is an error", () {
    BaseApi api = BaseApi();
    expect(api.getNetErrorException(""), HttpException(""));
  });
});
```

Comment: Can i see the exact error?

Comment: @rapaterno                                            getNetErrorException test/network/api/impl/BaseApi_test.dart
Testing started at 5:24 PM ...


Expected: _Exception:<Exception>
  Actual: _Exception:<Exception>

package:test_api                                   expect
package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart 461:3  expect
test/network/api/impl/BaseApi_test.dart 63:9       main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>                       it seems i'm comparing 2 different objects may be that's y i'm getting error but i don't know the solution

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for `expect` to tell if one `HttpException('')` is "equal" to another `HttpException('')` unless `HttpException` overrides `operator==`, which it doesn't do.  [The default `operator ==`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) that it inherits from `Object` tests for object *identity*.

You'd need to do:

```dart
expect(api.getNetErrorException(''), isA<HttpException>());
```

or if you must test the error message, you could create a custom matcher to check it:

```dart
expect(
  HttpException(''),
  allOf(
    isA<HttpException>(),
    predicate<HttpException>(
      (httpException) => httpException.message == ''),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Wonderful !! your test is passed 